# Why is "stroke-dasharray" not valid for some polygons

Tags: svg

For the following svg, why does the `stroke-dasharray` of line_1 and line_2 not take effect, and the drawing is still a solid line, but the line_3 draws a dotted line?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="296.0pt" width="574.3pt" viewBox="0.00 0.00 574.3 296.0">
<polygon id="line_1" points="194.2,121.0 194.2,175.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polygon>
<polygon id="line_2" points="294.2,121.0 294.2,275.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polygon>
<polygon id="line_3" points="228.4,148.0 262.6,148.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polygon>
</svg>
```

I tried to ask chatgpt, and chatgpt asked me to use the line tag, which I found to be useful, but I don't understand why when the stroke-dasharray attribute is set on the polygon tag, sometimes it takes effect and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: If you use a wider gap `stroke-dasharray="5,3"` or thinner stroke `stroke-width="0.5"`  you can see that stroke-dasharray really takes effect. 
So the '2' is somehow too narrow of a gap in some situations. With `stroke-width="0.5"` you can observe the overlap between the lines of length '5' (the overlap is partly because of non-integer values, instead of one fully red pixel, you may get a few pixels with lighter red). Also, note that a width/height in `...pt` does not take effect when embedding SVG in HTML. You should use `px` or no unit at all, e.g. `height="296.0px"` or `height="296.0"`

Comment: @qrsngky Ok,I found that different platforms have inconsistent handling of 2, which sometimes takes effect and sometimes does not. I will try to increase the gap, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Another thing is that, using a polygon means the stroke goes from A to B and then back to A, which increases the likelihood of the stroke overlapping with a gap when compared to a line (which is one line, from A to B)

Comment: `<path id="line_1" d="M194.2,121.0 194.2,175.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></path>` only goes one way (I used same thing except it's `path` instead of `polygon`, and `d` instead of `points`, and `M` is added as the first character of the `d` attribute) and you can see that the gaps are clearly shown, even though it's also `5,2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to make a polygon with two points (say A and B), it goes A to B *and then back to A* (closing itself).

That means the first part of the stroke (from A to B) will **overlap** with the second part (from B to A).
If the solid part of the stroke draws over a gap, the gap may "disappear" in some cases. (whether this happens depends on the total length of the line and the dash-strokearray)

In the following demo I changed the `polygon` to `path`, using the `d` attribute instead of `points`, and adding `M` as the first character of the `d`. Then it only goes from A to B.
Now, even for `5,2`, the gap is obvious.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="296.0px" width="574.3px" viewBox="0.00 0.00 574.3 296.0">
<path id="line_1" d="M194.2,121.0 194.2,175.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></path>
<path id="line_2" d="M294.2,121.0 294.2,275.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></path>
<path id="line_3" d="M228.4,148.0 262.6,148.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></path>
</svg>
```

I also changed "pt" in width/height to "px", because in an SVG tag embedded in HTML, a width/height attribute with "pt" has no effect.

Also, if you add `z` to the end of the `d` attribute, it becomes A->B->A again, you can see some of the gaps 'disappear' again.

---

Edit:
If you only need straight lines, you can simply use polyline instead of polygon. It uses the same `points` attribute as a polygon, but a polyline does not go back to the starting point.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="296.0" width="574.3" viewBox="0.00 0.00 574.3 296.0">
<polyline id="line_1" points="194.2,121.0 194.2,175.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polyline>
<polyline id="line_2" points="294.2,121.0 294.2,275.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polyline>
<polyline id="line_3" points="228.4,148.0 262.6,148.0 " fill="none" stroke-dasharray="5,2" stroke="#ff0000"></polyline>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's useful. obviously, my understanding of polygon is not enough. In fact, there is no problem after changing to path, even if pt is not changed to px.

Comment: @JamisonJiang The pt -> px change is about the size of the svg, not really about whether a path will overlap with itself. Without that, the svg may be scaled to fit the surrounding (in your case, it becomes larger than 547.3 x 296.0). If you press "Run code snippet" on your original post and click "Full page", you can check that the svg is displayed with a size of 765.72 x 394.66

Comment: Here is a good suggestion from @RobertLongson . I'll edit my post to add it as an alternative. It's definitely easier to convert from polygon to polyline than to a path. (But path is more powerful as it can do much more than just straight lines)